# Convert DateTime To A whole number no decimal int

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am close, I just can't quite figure out how to only get a whole number, and drop the '0' (short of just using Left 1 to capture the number.  However, I am sure that is atrocious syntax to do such.  This is what I have so far.  How could I just get an 8 from this?

```
CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 2015-05-18 08:00:00.000-2015-05-18 14:00:00.000, 108), ':', '')) As maxtimepossible
```

EDIT ---

```
Declare @arrivaltime datetime, @departuretime datetime, timeatwork int
SET @arrivaltime = '2015-05-18 08:00:00.000'
SET @departuretime = '2015-05-18 14:00:00.000'
SET @timeatwork = 0

@timeatwork = CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), departuretime-arrivaltime, 108), ':', '')) As maxtimepossible
```

Comment: What output are you expecting to get?  Give an example.  What data type is `2015-05-18 08:00:00.000-2015-05-18 14:00:00.000`?  Is it a character string?  Is it a datetime and you're trying to express that it's not a fixed value?

Comment: @BaconBits apology for my vagueness, please see edit and see if it helps to clarify what I am after.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you don't just do `select datediff(hour,@arrivaltime,@departuretime)`.  I also don't see how you can get 8 when the time is 8 AM and 2 PM.

Comment: @BaconBits Thats what I was after, thank you!

Comment: Then why didn't you ask that question?